# Draft posts who supposed to not show in a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i have a method in a controller, who have the work to display all the posts by user by ID. Every post have a *user_id* **(relation 1/M).** Every post have a ENUM (***status***) with 3 choices (*active*/*inactive*/**draft**)

my idea with the controller method is ONLY DISPLAY all the posts who the ***status*** as draft and the user_id must be the same as the post user_id.

this is the method (Controller):

```
public function draft(Post $post, User $user)
{
    $drafts = Post::where('status', __('draft'))
        ->where($post->user_id == auth()->user()->id)
        ->paginate(8);

    return view('post.draft', compact('drafts'));
}
```

The idea is to display all matching posts as draft and the logged user (id) equals user_id which comes to posts user_id.

This is the way how i display in the blade:

```
@forelse ($drafts as $draft)
    <div class="bg-white p-2">
        <h2 class="text-black">
            {{ $draft->title }}
        </h2>
    </div>
@empty
    <p>{{ __('There is no posts') }}</p>
@endforelse
```

in the models i have:

POST:

```
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

USER:

```
public function posts(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: in the factory i create 15 posts (with random status and users), the problem in the DB i have draft posts with the user_id whick i logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `draft` method should be as below,

```php
public function draft(User $user)
{
    $drafts = Post::where('status', 'draft')
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->paginate(8);

    return view('post.draft', compact('drafts'));
}
```

There are 2 issues in your `draft` method

1. You are using `__('draft')`, which will return the translation value of string `draft`. Check the usage of `__()` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings).
2. `where($post->user_id == auth()->user()->id)`. In `where()` you need to provide the column name i.e.`user_id`